# Defining custom pragmas in haskell

Tags: haskell, ghc

I am interested in possibility to define my own pragma in GHC.

I suppose, that i should add it to lexer and parser. But what should i write into parser, to tell GHC how to handle my pragma?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to add [additional alternations to the `topdecl` production in Parser.y](https://github.com/ghc/ghc/blob/2b7d9c2b96eb9da3cce7826df4a91c3426095528/compiler/parser/Parser.y#L779). There's no separate lexer modifications required. Following the examples of the DEPRECATED/WARNING/RULES pragmas, whose definitions also begin there, you'll have to define some additional datatypes and case-handling paperwork in modules such as `HsDecls` and `RnSource`, but if you follow the pattern of prior similar work it should be easy going. (I also believe the GHC developers are notoriously helpful on IRC and mailing lists.)